# Separating the template based on node value based on condition equals "true" XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to format a message in which when `<json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">true</json:boolean>` I want to eliminate that node and get only `<json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>`

```
Sample Message:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:object xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:array name="results">
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber"/>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription">PONumber__c not specified</json:string>
        </json:object>
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber">000100052774</json:string>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription">Work order's Product or Warehouse cannot be changed.</json:string>
        </json:object>
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber">000100052775</json:string>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">true</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription"/>
        </json:object>
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber">000100052983</json:string>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">true</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription"/>
        </json:object>
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber"/>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription">PONumber__c not specified</json:string>
        </json:object>
    </json:array>
    <json:boolean name="isSuccess">false</json:boolean>
</json:object>
```

**Desired output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:object xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:array name="results">
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber"/>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription">PONumber__c not specified</json:string>
        </json:object>
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber">000100052774</json:string>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription">Work order's Product or Warehouse cannot be changed.</json:string>
        </json:object>
        <json:object>
            <json:string name="RecordNumber"/>
            <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
            <json:string name="errorDescription">PONumber__c not specified</json:string>
        </json:object>
    </json:array>
    <json:boolean name="isSuccess">false</json:boolean>
</json:object>
```

Here is link for the 
[Code](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3L)

Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/json:object/json:array/json:object/json:boolean[normalize-space(.) = 'true']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Gives this output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd">
   <json:array name="results">
      <json:object>
         <json:string name="RecordNumber"/>
         <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
         <json:string name="errorDescription">PONumber__c not specified</json:string>
      </json:object>
      <json:object>
         <json:string name="RecordNumber">000100052774</json:string>
         <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
         <json:string name="errorDescription">Work order's Product or Warehouse cannot be changed.</json:string>
      </json:object>
      <json:object>
         <json:string name="RecordNumber">000100052775</json:string>true<json:string name="errorDescription"/>
      </json:object>
      <json:object>
         <json:string name="RecordNumber">000100052983</json:string>true<json:string name="errorDescription"/>
      </json:object>
      <json:object>
         <json:string name="RecordNumber"/>
         <json:boolean name="isRecordSuccess">false</json:boolean>
         <json:string name="errorDescription">PONumber__c not specified</json:string>
      </json:object>
   </json:array>
   <json:boolean name="isSuccess">false</json:boolean>
</json:object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:object[json:boolean[@name='isRecordSuccess']='true']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove any `json:object` that has a child `json:boolean` with (a) `@name` attribute equal to "isRecordSuccess", and (b) text value equal to "true".

Comment: Hi Michael, Can you please explain about the condition?

Comment: Thanks for the explaination